# JavaScript formula Math formula results in strange numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get my head around this. I have created a html form to calculate body fat % with a conditional field (based on what gender is choosen). The JavaScript formula gives the right answer for the male version, but a strange result for the female version. Both formulas are the same, only the variables differ.

Does anyone know what is causing this issue or am I missing something here?

This is my html form:

```
<div class="gf_browser_chrome gform_wrapper gform_legacy_markup_wrapper">
    <form enctype='multipart/form-data' id='WB_1'>
        <div class='gform_body gform-body'>
            <ul id='WB_fields_1' class='gform_fields top_label form_sublabel_below description_below'>
                <li id="geslacht"
                    class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibidivty_visible">
                    <label class='gfield_label' for='input_geslacht'>Geslacht<span class="gfield_required"><span
                                class="gfield_required gfield_required_asterisk">*</span></span></label>
                    <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_select'><select name='input_geslacht_1_1'
                            id='input_geslacht_1' class='small gfield_select' aria-required="true" aria-invadivd="false"
                            onchange="geslachtSwitch(this)">
                            <option value='Man'>Man</option>
                            <option value='Vrouw'>Vrouw</option>
                        </select></div>
                </li>
                <li id="lengte"
                    class="gfield gfield--width-full gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibidivty_visible">
                    <label class='gfield_label' for='input_lengte'>Lengte in cm<span class="gfield_required"><span
                                class="gfield_required gfield_required_asterisk">*</span></span></label>
                    <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_number'><input name='input_lengte_1_1'
                            id='input_lengte_1' type='text' value='' class='small' aria-required="true"
                            aria-invadivd="false" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="taille"
                    class="gfield gfield--width-full gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibidivty_visible">
                    <label class='gfield_label' for='input_taille'>Taille omtrek in cm<span
                            class="gfield_required"><span
                                class="gfield_required gfield_required_asterisk">*</span></span></label>
                    <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_number'><input name='input_taille_1_1'
                            id='input_taille_1' type='text' value='' class='small' aria-required="true"
                            aria-invadivd="false" aria-describedby="gfield_instruction_1_2" />
                        <div class='instruction ' id='gfield_instruction_1_2'>Voor mannen gemeten op navelhoogte, voor
                            vrouwen gemeten op het smalste punt.</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="nek"
                    class="gfield gfield--width-full gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibidivty_visible">
                    <label class='gfield_label' for='input_nek'>Nek omtrek in cm<span class="gfield_required"><span
                                class="gfield_required gfield_required_asterisk">*</span></span></label>
                    <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_number'><input name='input_nek_1_1' id='input_nek_1'
                            type='text' value='' class='small' aria-required="true" aria-invadivd="false"
                            aria-describedby="gfield_instruction_1_3" />
                        <div class='instruction ' id='gfield_instruction_1_3'>Gemeten net onder je strottenhoofd. Het
                            meetdivnt zit aan de voorkant wat lager dan aan de achterkant van je nek.</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="heup" style="display:none"
                    class="gfield gfield--width-full gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibidivty_visible">
                    <label class='gfield_label' for='input_heup'>Heup omtrek in cm<span class="gfield_required"><span
                                class="gfield_required gfield_required_asterisk">*</span></span></label>
                    <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_number'><input name='input_heup_1_1' id='input_heup_1'
                            type='text' value='' class='small' aria-required="true" aria-invadivd="false"
                            aria-describedby="gfield_instruction_1_4" />
                        <div class='instruction ' id='gfield_instruction_1_4'>Gemeten op het breedste punt.</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="button"
                    class="gfield gfield--width-full gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibidivty_visible">
                    <button style="color:white; background-color:black;" onclick="vetLoad()" type="button"
                        value="berekenen">VETPERCENTAGE BEREKENEN</button>
                </li>
                <li id="vet"
                    class="gfield gfield_calculation field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibidivty_visible">
                    <label class='gfield_label' for='input_vet'>Vetpercentage</label>
                    <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_number'><input name='input_vet_1_1' id='input_vet_1'
                            type='text' value='%' class='small' readonly="readonly" placeholder='%'
                            aria-invadivd="false" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is my JS script:

```
    function vetLoad() {
        geslacht = document.getElementById('input_geslacht_1');
        lengte = document.getElementById('input_lengte_1').value;
        taille = document.getElementById('input_taille_1').value;
        nek = document.getElementById('input_nek_1').value;
        heup = document.getElementById('input_heup_1').value;

        if (geslacht.value == "Man" || geslacht.options[geslacht.selectedIndex].value == "Man") {
            percentage = 86.010 * Math.log10(taille - nek) - 70.041 * Math.log10(lengte) + 30.30;
        }

        else if (geslacht.value == "Vrouw" || geslacht.options[geslacht.selectedIndex].value == "Vrouw") {
            percentage = 163.205 * Math.log10(taille + heup - nek) - 97.684 * Math.log10(lengte) - 104.912;
        }

        percentage0 = Math.round(percentage);
        document.getElementById('input_vet_1').value = percentage;
    }
</script>
```

UPDATE: Improved code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">geslacht
    function geslachtSwitch(geslacht) {
        if (geslacht.value == "Man" || geslacht.options[geslacht.selectedIndex].value == "Man") {
            document.getElementById('heup').style.display = "none";
        }

        if (geslacht.value == "Vrouw" || geslacht.options[geslacht.selectedIndex].value == "Vrouw") {
            document.getElementById('heup').style.display = "block";
        }
    }

    function vetLoad() {
        geslacht = document.getElementById('input_geslacht_1');
        lengte = document.getElementById('input_lengte_1').value;
        taille = document.getElementById('input_taille_1').value;
        nek = document.getElementById('input_nek_1').value;
        heup = document.getElementById('input_heup_1').value;

        if (geslacht.value == "Man" || geslacht.options[geslacht.selectedIndex].value == "Man") {
            percentage = 86.010 * Math.log10(taille - nek) - 70.041 * Math.log10(lengte) + 30.30;
        }

        else if (geslacht.value == "Vrouw" || geslacht.options[geslacht.selectedIndex].value == "Vrouw") {
            percentage = 163.205 * Math.log10(Number(taille) + Number(heup) - Number(nek)) - 97.684 * Math.log10(lengte) - 104.912;
        }

        percentage0 = Math.round(percentage);
        document.getElementById('input_vet_1').value = percentage0;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A running example would be helpful.

Comment: all those variables which read the `.value` of various inputs are strings, so your problem is that `taille + heup` will do string concatenation. You should convert the values to numbers first which the `+` operator or the `Number` function.

Comment: What do you mean by strange numbers ?

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: On top of Robin's comment, the reason it worked for Men is that for men, your first operation on the values is `-`, which will coerce its values to numbers before subtracting.  The first operation for Women is `+`, which will simply concatenate strings.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks, wrapping the variables individually into Number() function solved the problem. Im not sure what the best way is to solve this issue here, but I updated the code in my question. Is that the right way to finish this and help others. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ScottSauyet ah yes, I see it now. Thanks! That really clarifies :-D

Comment: No, a better way to finish this is to leave the question intact (once any edits have been made to clarify it) then ask those who've given you the relevant answer as comments (here Robin) whether they'd like to write it as an answer.  If so, accept that answer (and upvote it to if you like!)  If not, or  after a short wait, feel free to add your own answer. That's fine here. Choosing [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68368493/revisions) should let you roll back those changes.  (*Note*: If the question already has good answers, you don't need to ask the commenters for answers.)

Comment: (If you do edit the question, you might also want to remove the `math` and `logarithm` tags.  They turned out to be irrelevant.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond could you copy paste your comment as an asnwer :-) If not, I will answer it myself.

Im sorry, im a newbie here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of Robin who solved my problem:
*All those variables which read the .value of various inputs are strings, so your problem is that taille + heup will do string concatenation. You should convert the values to numbers first which the + operator or the Number function*

Reason why (by Scott):
*On top of Robin's comment, the reason it worked for Men is that for men, your first operation on the values is -, which will coerce its values to numbers before subtracting. The first operation for Women is +, which will simply concatenate strings.*

This is how my updated script looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">geslacht
    function geslachtSwitch(geslacht) {
        if (geslacht.value == "Man" || geslacht.options[geslacht.selectedIndex].value == "Man") {
            document.getElementById('heup').style.display = "none";
        }

        if (geslacht.value == "Vrouw" || geslacht.options[geslacht.selectedIndex].value == "Vrouw") {
            document.getElementById('heup').style.display = "block";
        }
    }

    function vetLoad() {
        geslacht = document.getElementById('input_geslacht_1');
        lengte = document.getElementById('input_lengte_1').value;
        taille = document.getElementById('input_taille_1').value;
        nek = document.getElementById('input_nek_1').value;
        heup = document.getElementById('input_heup_1').value;

        if (geslacht.value == "Man" || geslacht.options[geslacht.selectedIndex].value == "Man") {
            percentage = 86.010 * Math.log10(taille - nek) - 70.041 * Math.log10(lengte) + 30.30;
        }

        else if (geslacht.value == "Vrouw" || geslacht.options[geslacht.selectedIndex].value == "Vrouw") {
            percentage = 163.205 * Math.log10(Number(taille) + Number(heup) - Number(nek)) - 97.684 * Math.log10(lengte) - 104.912;
        }

        percentage0 = Math.round(percentage);
        document.getElementById('input_vet_1').value = percentage0;
    }
</script>
```